# Dealing with calculus manipulation

Tags: calculus

(To come to my question I will have to bore you with an introductory physical modeling, so please bear with me. The reason I ask this question here is because it has nothing to do physics but calculus.)

In physics there is a simplified model of rocket propulsion. It is assumed that the rocket has mass $M,$ some portion of it being the fuel, and the rocket propels itself by its engine ejecting burnt fuel. It is also assumed that the burnt fuel is ejected with constant speed $c$, relative to the rocket, in a direction opposite to that of the rocket's motion. The problem is to model this motion.

At time $t=t$ it is assumed that the velocity of the rocket is $\vec{v}$ and its mass is $M$. At time $t = t + \delta t$ let us assume that $\delta \ m$ amount of fuel is ejected and the rocket's velocity is $\vec{v} + \delta \vec{v}$.

Newton's $\vec{F}=m\vec{a}$ is not directly applicable (because mass is not constant) so physicists use a so called trick, that impulse equals change in momentum (which is mass times velocity, denoted by $p$). In the even more simplified version it is assumed that there are no external forces (hence no impulse). Thus (leaving aside the vector notation):

$$
\Delta p = (M - \delta m)(v + \delta v) + \delta m(v - c) - Mv = 0
$$

From which we have:

$$
\Delta p = M\delta v - c\delta m = 0
$$

(Textbooks denote rocket's mass with $m$ and the ejected fuel with $\delta m$ which I think is ultimately confusing. Among the ones I checked only *An Introduction to Mechanics* by Daniel Kleppner and Robert Kolenkow use a similar notation.)

It is assumed that $p, v, M, \ m$ are functions of time (thus $p(t), v(t), M(t), \ m(t)$). Taking the limit:

$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \left(\frac{\Delta p}{\delta t}\right) = \lim_{t \to 0} \left(M \frac{\delta v}{\delta t} - c\frac{\delta m}{\delta t}\right)
$$

Thus,

$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = M\frac{dv}{dt} - c\frac{dm}{dt}
$$

The above-mentioned textbook inserts the following line:

$$
\frac{dp}{dt} = M\frac{dv}{dt} + c\frac{dM}{dt}
$$

saying that:

> In this last equation we used the identity $dm/dt = −dM/dt,$ because
>   the expelled mass decreases the total mass of the rocket.

Here comes my question: I see where and why that minus sign comes from (and has nothing to do my question). But, mathematically, and from calculus point of view, how do we justify the identity $dm/dt = \pm dM/dt$ (depending whether mass is absorbed or ejected)? Especially because it also implies $dm = -dM$.

The only possible interpretation I can come up with is that that infinitesimal fuel ($dm$) is the same infinitesimal rocket mass ($dM$), but even that looks like a mixture of alchemy and abuse.

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you bothered by the idea that the rate of change of mass (an unsigned quantity) could carry a negative sign? Consider the following example: let $x(t)$ represent the volume of water in a cone, which is dripping into a bucket; the volume of water in the bucket is $y(t)$. If there are no other sources or sinks of water, $x(t)+y(t)$ is a constant by conservation of mass. Hence $x'(t)$ and $y'(t)$ have opposite signs, even though $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ are never negative. The same idea is in play here.

Answer (score 0):

The equation $\frac{dm}{dt}=-\frac{dM}{dt}$ isn't a mathematical consequence of an earlier equation. It is part of the system that we want the mathematics to model. We are simply not *interested* in unphysical solutions where $M(t)$ and $m(t)$ vary independently.

Comment: Thank you for your input. If $M(t)$ and $m(t)$ vary *dependently*, does is not imply that there should be some constant involved? (Unless they are actually the same.)

Comment: Sure, since $\frac{d}{dt}(m+M)=0$, we have that $m+M$ is an antiderivative of zero: that is, a constant.